# Leanback row transparent color for cards

Tags: java, android, chromecast, google-tv, leanback

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to change the background color of the items that are not currently in focus in my **Leanback** app:

[image]

The selected row has the transparent color so that only the box art is showing. However, the issue is the row that is not selected. It still seems to have a dark grey background instead of what I am wanting, transparent.

[image]

I've looked around my code and this is the code that looks to currently change the background when I select a box art item:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    sDefaultBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(parent.getContext(), R.color.default_background);
    sSelectedBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(parent.getContext(), R.color.selected_background);
    mDefaultCardImage = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parent.getContext(), R.drawable.movie);

    ImageCardView cardView =
            new ImageCardView(parent.getContext()) {
                @Override
                public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
                    updateCardBackgroundColor(this, selected);
                    super.setSelected(selected);
                }
            };

    cardView.setFocusable(true);
    cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    updateCardBackgroundColor(cardView, false);

    return new ViewHolder(cardView);
}
```

The **sDefaultBackgroundColor** is transparent and this is what's used for the focused row.

The **sSelectedBackgroundColor** is an orange color to indicate that an item in the row has focus.

The **mDefaultCardImage** is a placeholder for box art that is not currently there.

So these are the only ones I have found in my code that changes the color of the cards.

Anyone know what the code is for the non-focused row/box art?

Comment: Are you using ListRowPresenter for rows inside your app? the black overlay seems to be the list select effect imposed by ListRowPresenter.